# Is there a way, in meson, to overwrite the built-in options from the cross build definition file?

Tags: arm, meson-build

I'm currently evaluating different build-systems for embedded projects (ex: FreeRTOS based) and I came across meson. I find it good, mostly the idea to have a cross build definition file to define how my project needs to be compiled.

Nevertheless, I do have an issue with some of the base options such as:

- b_pch
- b_staticpic

That is, as default, set to `true`. In my project, these options generate a **wrong binary**...

The current solution, as meson propose it, is:

```
meson debug --cross-file boards/SensGate/meson_config_stm32l4_gcc8.ini -Db_pch=false -Db_staticpic=false
cd debug && ninja hex
```

But I somehow do not find it pretty to have to define compile and linker options outside the cross build definition file...

**I was wondering if there was a way maybe to overwrite these options in the file itself...**

If not, do you think I should create a ticket in the meson project to request this feature?

I would expect something like:

```
[binaries]
c = 'arm-none-eabi-gcc'

[buildin_option] # New section?
b_pch = false
b_staticpic = false

[properties]
objcopy = 'arm-none-eabi-objcopy'
objcopy_args = [
    ...]
c_args = [
    ...]
c_link_args = [
    ...]

[host_machine]
...
```

Comment: Why not to overwrite the defaults in project() function?

Comment: @matt, do you have somewhere a better link than: https://mesonbuild.com/Build-options.html#startup-project? Something like `project('name', 'c', default_options: ['b_pch=false', 'b_staticpic=false'])`?

Comment: When in doubt read the reference manual: https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#project

Comment: Hi @Matt, with your comment I manage to get what I wanted, thanks! I will publish my answer in 5 - 10 min

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Matt for the support here.

My cross build definition file looks like:

```
[binaries]
...

[properties]
...
project_configuration = [
    'b_pch=false',
    'b_staticpic=false']
...

[host_machine]
...
```

and in my root `meson.build`, I have:

```
# Define the project
project('Project', 'c', default_options: meson.get_cross_property('project_configuration'))
...
```

This way, I just need to call as commands:

```
meson debug --cross-file boards/SensGate/meson_config_stm32l4_gcc8.ini
cd debug && ninja hex
```